# How to specify the path to the element through multiple div?

Tags: html, css

I recently work with HTML and I need help.

I have this page and I want to apply CSS to my button, but I'm a little confused how to correctly specify the path to this button.

```html
<div class="cart">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cart-info">
      <div class="order">
        <form action="order" method="POST">

          <h4>Pay type: </h4>
          <select name="pay_type">
            <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
            <option value="MasterCard">MasterCard</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>

          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Count </th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach items="${cartItems}" var="items">
              <tr>
                <td> ${items.key.name} </td>
                <td> ${items.value} </td>
                <td> ${items.key.price * items.value} </td>
              </tr>
            </c:forEach>
          </table>


          <div align="right">
            <h4> Total price: ${sessionScope.totalPrice} </h4>
          </div>

          <input name="cart_id" placeholder="cart number" required><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
      </div>
      </form>


    </div>
```

I'm trying this way, but it's not working

```
div.cart div.container div.cart-info div.order form input[type="submit"]{
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
}
```

How to specify the path to the button?

Comment: What do you mean by a "*path to the button*"? You have a table, not a canvas. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Make your button more obvious? Or are you talking about the **selector** for your button? Could you please update your question so that it adds a little **context** to help clarify your **intent**?

Comment: Do note that your HTML is invalid as it is presented in your question. Your second-to-last `</div>` is before the `</form>` rather than after it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify a path to the input[type="submit"] button if you want to style it with CSS. All you need to do is create a CSS class or an ID selector, add the styles you want to it and then add that class/id to the input[type="submit"] button like so.

CSS

```
.btn-submit{
//this is a CSS class, can be reused
     background-color: green;
     color: white;
   }
```

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn-submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, why do you do it like that? It is better that you create a class and give it the style through the class, or through an id. You can also give a class to the tag 'form', and navigate to the button, it is very understandable and unnecessary to do it that way.

but hey, what happens is that your html is badly structured and some of the div tags that you opened, you never close them. Here I give you the html.

```
<div class="cart">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cart-info">
      <div class="order">
        <form action="order" method="POST">

          <h4>Pay type: </h4>
          <select name="pay_type">
            <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
            <option value="MasterCard">MasterCard</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>

          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Count </th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach  items="${cartItems}" var="items">
              <tr>
                <td> ${items.key.name} </td>
                <td> ${items.value} </td>
                <td> ${items.key.price * items.value} </td>
              </tr>
            </c:forEach>
          </table>


          <div align="right"> <h4> Total price: ${sessionScope.totalPrice} </h4> </div>

          <input name="cart_id" placeholder="cart number" required><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you work

Answer (score 0):

I prefer just to use something like this:

`.cart form input[type="submit"]{
  ...
}`

It is concise and semantic and think is better to set a class for the form instead for the submit button. But not needed.